# Flux of $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z) = (y-z,z-x,x-y)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

At class, I have been proposed the following exercise:

> *Consider the vector field $$\mathbf{f}(x,y,z) = (y-z,z-x,x-y).$$  Calculate the flux of $\mathbf{f}$ through the surface $$S = \{x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2ax,\, x^2+y^2 \leq 2bx,\,z \geq 0,\,b > a >0\},$$ which is oriented upward, using Stokes' Theorem.*

My first idea was to use Gauss' Theorem. However, I am specifically asked to use Stokes' Theorem to calculate the flux.

My question is: Which application of Stokes' Theorem should I use then?

Perhaps it is not immediate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should include your attempts to solve the problem. Otherwise, I don't think you'll get an answer here at MSE. Only saying you have attempted Gauss' Theorem isn't enough. Try to also include any attempts you made using Stokes' Theorem, which is your actual question.

Comment: The surface isn't closed, so Gauss's theorem isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: Also, are you sure it wasn't $a > b > 0$? Otherwise you have to consider the cases $b > 2a$ and $b < 2a$ separately.

Comment: Yes, it is b>a>0.